# ReSharper: Replace interface with base class

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way to tell ReSharper to replace *IClass* with *ClassBase* that implements *IClass* in places where it possible?

The problem is, I have too much implementations of some interface and half of their logic can be put in abstrac class, that implements this interface.

The best solution I came so far is to Find And Replace each one of them, and then fix errors with hands.

Comment: Manually edit the interface definition and make it an abstract class instead. Then you can move methods from derived classes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for a better workflow, I would do the following:

1. Turn the interface into (abstract) class
2. Rename the class
3. Extract an interface
4. Invoke *Use base type where possible* on new base class, select interface

Although it's not a single-step solution, this keeps semantics intact.

Comment: And how about functions signature?

Comment: @eocron06 What do you mean exactly? They should be no exception to that approach.

Comment: If you change interface to class and rename it -> you will change functions signature. That's not good.

Comment: I get your point, but then the question is still unclear. What occurrence do you want to replace? I guess just the inheritance? Then, follow point 4 in my list.